# I want to know how to simplify this code

Tags: jquery

I really just want to know how to collapse this code. It works fine but I cam growing tired of always having to copy and paste many lines of jquery. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
http://jsfiddle.net/eE35W/5/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".creep1").mouseover(function(){
    $(".deep1").animate({
      left:'0px',
      opacity:'100',
      height:'100px',
      width:'300px'
    });
  });
  $(".creep1").mouseout(function(){
    $(".deep1").animate({
      left:'0px',
      opacity:'0.5',
      height:'100px',
      width:'10px'
    });
  });
  $(".creep2").mouseover(function(){
    $(".deep2").animate({
      left:'0px',
      opacity:'100',
      height:'100px',
      width:'300px'
    });
  });
  $(".creep2").mouseout(function(){
    $(".deep2").animate({
      left:'0px',
      opacity:'0.5',
      height:'100px',
      width:'10px'
    });
  });
  $(".creep3").mouseover(function(){
    $(".deep3").animate({
      left:'0px',
      opacity:'100',
      height:'100px',
      width:'300px'
    });
  });
  $(".creep3").mouseout(function(){
    $(".deep3").animate({
      left:'0px',
      opacity:'0.5',
      height:'100px',
      width:'10px'
    });
  });
  $(".creep").click(function(){
    $(".wrap1, .wrap2, .wrap3").toggle({
      left:'0px',
      opacity:'100',
      height:'100px',
      width:'300px'
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I think this belongs to another stack exchange

Comment: this question belongs to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Well for starters you can use `.hover` instead of `.mouseover` and `.mouseout`.

Comment: You could do a for loop from 1 to 3

Comment: this question belongs to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Put the values for position etc into `data-` attributes and then you can use a single event (well two events) to handle all of the animations.

Comment: Might help you http://jsfiddle.net/eE35W/6/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creep1, creep2... creepn and deep1, deep2... deepn, simply assign common classes **creep** and **deep**. And simplify your code as,

```
$(".creep").mouseout(function()
{
    $(this).next().animate({ // Since deep is next div to creep (as per your code)
      left:'0px',
      opacity:'0.5',
      height:'100px',
      width:'10px'
    });
});
```

Similarly you could write your `mouseover` function.

Answer (score 0):

If you change to a common class instead of numbered ones you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".creep" ).hover(function(){
     $(this).next().animate({
       opacity:'100',
       width:'300px'
       // since you are not changing the values 
       // of the other properties they have been left out
     });
   }),function(){
     $(this).next().animate({
       opacity:'0.5',
       width:'10px'
     });
   });
  };
 //remaining code
});
```